# Triggers Oracle || Backup records to another table after insert

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have to backup inserted record to another table using trigger.

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Zadanie1
BEFORE INSERT ON ZLECENIA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Record inserted to table!')
  INSERT INTO ZLECENIA_BACKUP (ID_ZLECENIA,ID_USLUGI,ID_KLIENTA,ID_PRACOWNIKA,DATA_ZL)
  VALUES (:new.ID_ZLECENIA, :new.ID_USLUGI, :new.ID_KLIENTA, :new.ID_PRACOWNIKA, :NEW.ID_PRACOWNIKA, :NEW.DATA_ZL);
 dbms_output.put_line('Backup created!')
END Zadanie1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing few `semicolons` at the end of each statement, Use the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ZADANIE1 BEFORE
    INSERT ON ZLECENIA
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Record inserted to table!');
    INSERT INTO ZLECENIA_BACKUP (
        ID_ZLECENIA,
        ID_USLUGI,
        ID_KLIENTA,
        ID_PRACOWNIKA,
        DATA_ZL
    ) VALUES (
        :NEW.ID_ZLECENIA,
        :NEW.ID_USLUGI,
        :NEW.ID_KLIENTA,
        :NEW.ID_PRACOWNIKA,
        :NEW.ID_PRACOWNIKA,
        :NEW.DATA_ZL
    );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Backup created!');
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, but still same error: ZADANIE1 is invalid and failed re-validation.

Comment: use `SHOW ERROR` to check for what is the error. It might be an error related to the `INSERT` statement table.

Comment: INSERT INTO Zlecenia VALUES(32,1,1,5,'2008-11-11'); , and error: trigger 'STUDENT17B_5.ZADANIE2' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: Error comes only when i wan't to create backup, simple dbms_output.put_line works well.